# Bash + SSH + Grep not generating output

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I'm trying to use the script below to extract values from the `df` command on remote servers, then record to a log file. SSH keys are in place and no password is needed (this is not the problem).

It's getting hung up, however, and not spitting back output.

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
export PATH

SERVERLIST=/opt/scripts/server-list.dat

while IFS='|' read -u 3 hostname; do

echo evaluating $hostname...

SIZE=$(ssh $hostname | df -Pkhl | grep '/Volumes/UserStorage$' | awk '{print $2}')
 echo $SIZE


done 3< $SERVERLIST

exit 0
```

Comment: You're not giving a command argument to `ssh`, so it's logging into the server interactively.

Comment: How would I change it to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `df` on the remote system, not pipe the output of an interactive `ssh` to it:

```
SIZE=$(ssh -n $hostname df -Pkhl | grep '/Volumes/UserStorage$' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Also, use the `-n` option to `ssh` to keep it from trying to read from `stdin`, which would consume the rest of the lines from the server list file.

Comment: yes, that did the trick, thanks! I'll mark this as answered as soon as the time limit arrives...cheers!

Comment: if your grep support `-P` then you don't need to go for awk `grep -oP '^\s*\S+\s+\K\S+(?=.*/Volumes/UserStorage$)'`